# run gvfs-mount as user in a script owned by root for networkmanager dispatcher

Tags: mount, sudo, networkmanager, su, gvfs

I'm trying to create a script to auto mount using gvfs-mount for NetworkManager dispatcher. The dispatcher requires the script to be owned by root.

Running `gvfs-mount smb://path/` works in terminal as the user.

I've found 2 ways to run a command as another user from root, but none of them work.

```
$ su -c 'gvfs-mount smb://path/' user
[sudo] password for user:
Error mounting location: volume doesn't implement mount

$ sudo -u user gvfs-mount smb://path/
Error mounting location: volume doesn't implement mount
```

Comment: The sudo command should be `sudo -u user gvfs-mount smb://nas/downloads/`. `sudo` doesn't run a shell, it runs the command directly.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, but now I get the same error as above, `Error mounting location: volume doesn't implement mount`

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I have a similar problem

Comment: I believe I did eventually solve my problem. Unfortunately, I've stopped using Linux for a long time, so I can't help you.